# Spring Turbine Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, hystrix, turbine

I am currently using an authenticated microservices arch with Hystrix.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableTurbine
public class HystrixServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "hystrix");
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "testnext.keystore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "testnext.truststore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "test");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test");

    SpringApplication.run(GladHystrixServerApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

On the other microservices I am using a OAuth2RestTemplate for all the communication between them. However in this case I can't control the requests to add the authentication.

My first thought was to use an interceptor to add a parameter (the access token) but I can't seem to intercept any of the requests done by turbine in background.

Does anyone else have some idea on how to intercept the requests or a better solution to do this?

Comment: How about using `@EnableOAuth2Sso` http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/EnableOAuth2Sso.html